# Graph API to PSTN number - call state changes to establishing , But not receiving call on the landline number

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing an app using Graph API to call a PSTN number - call state changes to establishing , But not receiving call on the landline number

Referring

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-10-create-peer-to-peer-pstn-call-with-application-hosted-media

can someone help please?

```
# Securely storing the credentials
$TenantId = "XXXXX-49d3-40ba-a541-4b63e8e0fdc5"
$ClientId = "XXXXX-d9e7-40a7-8ed7-a915969a6833"
$ClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force

# Function to obtain an access token
function Get-GraphAccessToken {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$TenantId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ClientId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][System.Security.SecureString]$ClientSecret
    )

    $TokenBody = @{
        Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
        Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        Client_Id     = $ClientId
        Client_Secret = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("", $ClientSecret).Password
    }

    $TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $TokenBody -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    return $TokenResponse.access_token
}

# Obtain Access Token
$AccessToken = Get-GraphAccessToken -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $ClientId -ClientSecret $ClientSecret

# Convert the AccessToken to a SecureString
$SecureAccessToken = $AccessToken | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

# Connect to Microsoft Graph using SecureString
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $SecureAccessToken

# Prepare parameters for creating a call
$params = @{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.call"
    direction = "outgoing"
    subject = "call with application hosted media"
    callbackUri = "https://b744-14-142-211-86.ngrok-free.app/callback"
    source = @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.participantInfo"
        identity = @{
            "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.identitySet"
            applicationInstance = @{
                "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.identity"
                displayName = "PPCall"
                id = "525b3e87-1127-483a-bc43-0a99c51a8db0"
            }
        }
    }
    targets = @(
        @{
            "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo"
            identity = @{
                "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.identitySet"
                phone = @{
                    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.identity"
                    id = "+14086220061"
                }
            }
        }
    )
    requestedModalities = @("audio")
    mediaConfig = @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig"
        blob = "a.wav"
    }
    tenantId = $TenantId
}

# Error handling for creating a call
try {
    $callResponse = New-MgCommunicationCall -BodyParameter $params
    $callId = $callResponse.Id
    Write-Host "Call created successfully. Call ID: $callId"
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error in creating call: $_"
}
```

Console Results :

> The thread 0x5974 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x5c94 has
> exited with code 0 (0x0).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/callback
> application/json 406
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Route matched with {action = "OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync",
> controller = "PlatformCall"}. Executing controller action with
> signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync() on controller
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executing action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) - Validation state: Valid
> VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot:Information: 2024-01-14T04:47:59.6223Z
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997 pid:16532 tid:60 (Bot.cs:270
> NotificationProcessor_OnNotificationReceivedAsync): { "value": {
> "$id": "1", "$values": [ { "changeType": "Updated", "resourceUrl":
> "/communications/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resource": "/app/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resourceData": { "callChainId":
> "526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997", "state": "Establishing",
> "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call" }, "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification" } ] } } { "HttpLogData": {
> "Method": "POST", "Url": "https://localhost:5001/callback", "Headers":
> [ "Scenario-Id: 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997",
> "Client-Request-Id: e7ceecce-b081-4314-a1c7-7ab4358ffe45",
> "X-Microsoft-Tenant: (redacted)" ], "TransactionDirection":
> "Incoming", "TraceType": "HttpRequest", "TenantId":
> "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" } }
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot), returned result
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 8.8178ms.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) in 11.6675ms
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> finished in 17.2779ms 202
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/callback
> application/json 428
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Route matched with {action = "OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync",
> controller = "PlatformCall"}. Executing controller action with
> signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync() on controller
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executing action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) - Validation state: Valid
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/callback
> application/json 792
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Route matched with {action = "OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync",
> controller = "PlatformCall"}. Executing controller action with
> signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync() on controller
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executing action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) - Validation state: Valid
> VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot:Information: 2024-01-14T04:48:02.1600Z
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997 pid:16532 tid:49 (Bot.cs:270
> NotificationProcessor_OnNotificationReceivedAsync): { "value": {
> "$id": "1", "$values": [ { "changeType": "Updated", "resourceUrl":
> "/communications/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resource": "/app/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resourceData": { "callChainId":
> "526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997", "direction": "Outgoing",
> "state": "Established", "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call" },
> "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification" } ] } } {
> "HttpLogData": { "Method": "POST", "Url":
> "https://localhost:5001/callback", "Headers": [ "Scenario-Id:
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997", "Client-Request-Id:
> 952cca9c-ac69-4901-9883-0c9836831c86", "X-Microsoft-Tenant:
> (redacted)" ], "TransactionDirection": "Incoming", "TraceType":
> "HttpRequest", "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" } }
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot), returned result
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 9.2287ms.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) in 14.4217ms
> VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot:Information: 2024-01-14T04:48:02.1637Z
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997 pid:16532 tid:63 (Bot.cs:270
> NotificationProcessor_OnNotificationReceivedAsync): { "value": {
> "$id": "1", "$values": [ { "changeType": "Updated", "resourceUrl":
> "/communications/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resource": "/app/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resourceData": { "callChainId":
> "526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997", "mediaState": { "audio":
> "Active", "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callMediaState" }, "state":
> "Established", "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
> "meetingCapability": { "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.meetingCapability", "allowTranslatedCaptions": true,
> "allowTranslatedTranscriptions": true, "recorderAllowed": [] },
> "meetingProperties": { "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.meetingProperties", "meetingLabel":
> "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" }, "coOrganizers": [] },
> "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification" } ] } } {
> "HttpLogData": { "Method": "POST", "Url":
> "https://localhost:5001/callback", "Headers": [ "Scenario-Id:
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997", "Client-Request-Id:
> c9944fa9-7eaf-4dfb-b54c-98c18c2778b7", "X-Microsoft-Tenant:
> (redacted)" ], "TransactionDirection": "Incoming", "TraceType":
> "HttpRequest", "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" } }
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> finished in 19.9873ms 202
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot), returned result
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 9.9369ms.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) in 13.2163ms
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> finished in 17.533ms 202
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/callback
> application/json 1057
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Route matched with {action = "OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync",
> controller = "PlatformCall"}. Executing controller action with
> signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync() on controller
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executing action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) - Validation state: Valid
> VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot:Information: 2024-01-14T04:48:08.4273Z
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997 pid:16532 tid:49 (Bot.cs:270
> NotificationProcessor_OnNotificationReceivedAsync): { "value": {
> "$id": "1", "$values": [ { "changeType": "Deleted", "resourceUrl":
> "/communications/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resource": "/app/calls/411f5700-550f-4cdb-a342-34f37a6ca70d",
> "resourceData": { "callChainId":
> "526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997", "resultInfo": { "code": 200,
> "message": "The conversation has ended. DiagCode: 200#1000003.@",
> "subcode": 1000003, "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.resultInfo" },
> "state": "Terminated", "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
> "meetingCapability": { "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.meetingCapability", "allowTranslatedCaptions": true,
> "allowTranslatedTranscriptions": true, "recorderAllowed": [] },
> "meetingProperties": { "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.meetingProperties", "meetingLabel":
> "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" }, "coOrganizers": [],
> "terminationSender": { "application": { "id":
> "56aa0a8f-4cd3-446b-8146-0023476a5ff2", "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.identity" }, "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.identitySet" } }, "@odata.type":
> "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification" } ] } } { "HttpLogData": {
> "Method": "POST", "Url": "https://localhost:5001/callback", "Headers":
> [ "Scenario-Id: 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997",
> "Client-Request-Id: c7d98660-fe90-4948-a0cd-709a9d53ebf1",
> "X-Microsoft-Tenant: (redacted)" ], "TransactionDirection":
> "Incoming", "TraceType": "HttpRequest", "TenantId":
> "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" } }
> VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot:Information: 2024-01-14T04:48:08.4369Z
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997 pid:16532 tid:49 (Bot.cs:435
> CleanupCall): Cleaning up call
> VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot:Information: 2024-01-14T04:48:08.4397Z
> 526dabeb-988c-4177-ab2b-fa6f17766997 pid:16532 tid:49 (Bot.cs:449
> CleanupCall): File to be deleted does not exist.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action method
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot), returned result
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 18.4511ms.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
> Executed action
> Sample.VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot.Controller.PlatformCallController.OnIncomingBotCallUserRequestAsync
> (VoiceRecorderAndPlaybackBot) in 21.3134ms
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
> finished in 26.5816ms 202  The program '[16532] dotnet.exe' has exited
> with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Could you please confirm whether it is working with Cell Phone number?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft i had only +14086220061 this test number to call. I have updated the calling code and the BOT results. can you check and let me know whats wrong

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft tried with a mobile number. same same results , it doesnt work

Comment: This call requires an application instance with a PSTN number assigned. For details, see [Assign a phone number to your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number#assign-a-phone-number-to-your-bot). Could you please confirm if performed this step?

Comment: yes this is done, Please check @Meghana-MSFT   


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstance

ApplicationId                    DisplayName ObjectId                        PhoneNumber      TenantId                             UserPrincipalName
-------------                        ----------- --------                             -----------      --------                             -----------------
9cc48ef5-d9e7-40a7-8ed7-XXXXX PPCall      525b3e87-1127-483a-bc43-XXXXXXX tel:+17577344794 bc2a8d6c-49d3-40ba-a541-xxxx PPCall@sfc.us

Comment: Engineering team has looked into the logs and asked the following details. Could you please check the licenses which are assigned to the resource account(app instance).

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into above details?